# How to get Eclipse to move cursor across words on Ctrl+Alt+<arrow-key>?

Tags: macos, eclipse

I am on Mac OS X, and no matter what I change in Keys in Preferences, I get highly unorthodox and to me completely alien behavior where the selection changes to engulf the wider parent scope (in brackets). I am used to other editors where holding Ctrl+Alt and left or right arrow key moves selection endpoints and the cursor across word boundaries. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse allows you change key bindings for commands. For example "Previous Word" command can be changed to Cmd + Left Arrow.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F

From the wiki...

Display and Edit the Current Keyboard Shortcuts

To see the current key configuration and its keyboard shortcuts, choose the Eclipse > Preferences menu command to open the Eclipse workbench Preferences. Select the General > Editor > Keys page.

Type "Previous Word" in the command search, then click on the "Binding" field. Then do the key (e.g. Cmd + left arrow) then apply.

Comment: I tried to mess with Keys preferences pane - it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in eclipse that seems to have been around for a while where the welcome screen causes the typical CTRL-Arrow combination to stop working.  In Eclipse Neon I was able to solve this issue by unchecking the box to always show the welcome screen and restarting eclipse.

Here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341928/eclipse-ctrlright-does-nothing).